# How to Attach Modal Dialogue to Main Window in JavaFX?

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx, scenebuilder

Examples of Attached Modal Dialogues:

[image]

[image: Another Example]

[image: Another Example]

[image: Last example]

Is there any way to bring this to JavaFX?

Comment: See also [*Support for Mac OS X sheets*](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8092323)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find support for **attached dialogs** out of the JavaFX box... So, how I would do it...

- The dialog part: there's this,  *no way I'm beating it* example [gist](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1887631)
- And a tweak to the CSS file - the `.modal-dialog` styleClass:

  - `-fx-position: fixed`
  - `-fx-top: 0`